# What does "public class Nir<E>" mean?

Tags: java, generics

What does it mean when people write `public class Nir<E>` as the name of the class?

Does it mean that the instances of `Nir` will be collection of type `E`? 
I don't really get it. Is it just a declaration that the methods in the Nir will use collections?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`E` is a generic type parameter. `Nir<E>` is read `Nir` of `E`. It says that `Nir` is a class that is in some way related to `E`.

`Collection<E>` uses generics to say it contains `E`s.

`Class<E>` says it describes `E`.

`Comparator<E>` says it compares `E`s.

There are many uses for generics.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `Nir` is a [generic type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html). When you construct an instance of `Nir`, you have to specify a concrete type instead of the placeholder `<E>`.

A typical use of generics is with collections, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This is the mechanism that allow you to pass in an argument to the generics system when you *use* the `Nir` class and have placeholders for it in the code.

If for instance, you have in your Nir class

```
public E getResult()
```

and you need an instance of Nir, you type

```
Nir<String> nir = new Nir<String>();
String s = nir.getResult();
```

This means that the `E` in Nir.java for *this* invocation is `String` and you can immediately assign the return value from `getResult()` to a String object.

Answer (score 1):

The `<E>` part is called the generic parameter.

You can later instantiate `Nir` with a specific type such as `new Nir<Integer>()`
A simple example would be the `ArrayList<T>`. It's a generic class to store a list of any type. You can create an instance of it specifying the type of objects you would want to store, for eg. `new ArrayList<String>()` for strings. It is generic and at the same time type safe.

You might want to look into the [Generic Types documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a head start.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html